# jqgrid - editing a newly added row

Tags: jquery, forms, grid, addition, edit

When a new record is added via a form add, and the DB has a sequential key, the value for the id of the new record is not correct in the row that is auto populated in the grid. Is there a way to make jquery get the actual new id of the grid from the db, and populate this correctly in the new row without reloading the gird?

Answer (score 0):

Sure; have the form add return the new ID/record via JSON. Take that ID and data, construct the new HTML accordingly, and append the new row to the end of the table.

Comment: Yes, agree that would do it. Any idea why jq grid does not do this as standard functionality?

Comment: It [looks like it might](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods), see the `addRowData` method.

Comment: hmm interesting, I'll take a further look into it. Thanks for the pointers